# Sporadic corruption of files being uploaded

Tags: python, django

The below piece of code takes a file sent in an HTTP Request (Ajax) and saves it to the server. The code was written by someone else, but I had to modify it recently to add a unique identifier to the file so that existing files with the same name don't get overwritten. Essentially, I added these lines:

```
#uid is a GUID
if os.path.isfile(destination):
            destination = os.path.splitext(destination)[0] + str(uid) + os.path.splitext(destination)[1]
            name  = os.path.splitext(name)[0] + str(uid) + os.path.splitext(name)[1]
```

The problem I am seeing now is that **some times** the files for which I add the UID to the file name to guarantee uniqueness, end up being corrupted. It doesn't always happen - most of the times the files are saved correctly but in at least 4 cases out of 11 in the last 7 days, the files have been corrupted and it only happened to the files for which the UID was added to the name before saving it to the file system. Is there anything wrong with this code that may cause file corruption?

Here's the full context of the method being used:

```
if form.is_valid():
        id = request.REQUEST.get('id','')
        file = request.FILES['file']
        chunk = request.REQUEST.get('chunk','0')
        chunks = request.REQUEST.get('chunks','0')
        name = request.REQUEST.get('name','')
        destination = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/files/%s' % name
        # If the code goes into the below IF, the file MAY get corrupted.
        if os.path.isfile(destination):
            destination = os.path.splitext(destination)[0] + str(uid) + os.path.splitext(destination)[1]
            name  = os.path.splitext(name)[0] + str(uid) + os.path.splitext(name)[1]
        with open(destination, ('wb' if chunk == '0' else 'ab')) as f:  
            for content in file.chunks():  
                f.write(content)  
        if int(chunk) + 1 >= int(chunks):
            if not Attachment.objects.filter(uuid=uid,user=username,name=name):
                form.save(name,username,uid,id)

    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps({"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : None, "id" : "id"}), mimetype='text/plain; charset=UTF-8')  
    return response
```

Comment: When is the uid generated? It looks like this supports manual upload chunking, i.e. upload only the first part of a file in one request, then upload another part (incrementing `?chunk=i`) in a subsequent request. If you generate the uid for each request, the chunks end up in different files. Happens only when more than one chunk is used.

Comment: @dhke very interesting theory... The uid is initialized from this code. `uid = request.session.get('uuid')` and if I understand correctly, that is the browser's session id, which should be the same even if the file takes more than 1 chunk, no? I am a completely NOOB in python / django, sorry :-/

Comment: `request.session.get('uuid')` is a session variable with name `uuid`. I don't know where this is set, however (it's not standard), but that is maybe part of the application support code. Django's own session id/key is available via  `request.session.session_key`.

Comment: @dhke Thank you very much, you were right on the money from the very first comment. I was under the impression that the uid was really the same session id but apparently is not. I replicated the problem using a 2MB file and once I switched to using `request.session.session_key` the problem was fixed. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the lifetime of the file `uid`. This is not a problem for a single file upload, but becomes a problem when the *chunked uploading* functionality of the code is used.

Because `uid` is generated per request and each file chunk is uploaded in a separate request, each chunk receives a different `uid`. This in turn causes *chunk 1* to go *file 1*, *chunk 2* to *file 2*, resulting in corruption.

One workaround is to set the `uid` based on the session key, available via `request.session.session_key`. Because of the cryptographic properties of the session key, it should also be "reasonably unique" for the purpose.

Note however, that there is a potential security risk, if the file path is exposed to the web or even if `/media/` can be directory-listed, because you are exposing the session key to the web (the session key is the only thing that protects access to an active session).

Another, more secure method is to assign a unique UUID to each session via a session variable. This is probably best done in [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/):

```
class SessionUUIDMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(request):
        session_uuid = request.session.get('uuid', None)
        if not session_uuid:
            session_uuid = uuid.uuid1()
            request.session['uuid'] = session_uuid
```

This disconnects the unique id from the session key.